# How to get image with image style path to a twig template

Tags: theming

I had created a field called tv_adbackground on the settings filed to be a ble to uplaod a background image.

The upload works great!

How to get the path of the file or the image style medium or thumbinal in to a twig template like this?

```
...
 <div id="advertisement"> <!-- background-image uploaded on theme settings page should be used here ->


 <div id=advertisement-dimmer>

 <h3 class="adheading">{{ tv_adheading }}</h3>

<div id="admessage">{{ tv_admessage }}

<div class="btn-group adbuttons" role="group" aria-label="Basic    
example">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><a 
style="color:#fff;" href="/signup">Register</a>   
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a 
href="/user/login">Login</a></button>
</div>
</div>
```

I would use css to retrive thte image path but with css i dont get teh variable to get the file path.

I am new to drupal 8 so it would be great if there will be  anyone to help

Comment: in theme.theme files you  have to write something like this in preprocess function $variables['logopath'] =$base_url.'/'. drupal_get_path('theme','your-theme') . '/images/image-name.svg';   , then print the variable {{ logopath }} in your theme

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the help of two additional modules.

- [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) - to get the path to the image and
- [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) - to get the image style version of an image.

Then in your Twig template you would use something like this to get the image style path:

```
{{ content.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('medium') }}
```

where `field_image` is the name of the image field.

If you use something like the Media module then your images come from a referenced entity. In that case you could use

```
{{ file_url(content.field_referenced_entity | field_target_entity.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('medium')) }}
```

and `field_referenced_entity` would be the media/entity reference field and `field_image` the name of the image field on the referenced entity. Notice that in the second case the whole path is wrapped in `file_url()`.

Comment: You are a saint!

Answer (score 0):

As per @Clive on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754661/drupal-8-images-with-image-style).

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

$path = 'public://images/image.jpg';
$url = ImageStyle::load('style_name')->buildUrl($path);
```

This is the equivalent of `image_style_url('style', uri)` in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image with custom style in node.html.twig -

```
<img src="{{ node.IMAGE_FIELD.entity.uri.value | image_style('IMAGE_STYLE_NAME') }}">
```